# Python function to create dynamically calculated pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, logic

I have the following sample dataframe:

| hand | player | event | amount | stack_size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #345 | paired | win | 144 | 552 |
| #345 | paired | bet returned | 72 | 552 |
| #345 | paired | bets | 72 | 552 |
| #345 | paired | bets | 43 | 552 |
| #345 | paired | raises | 18 | 552 |
| #345 | paired | stack | 0 | 552 |
| #345 | paired | starting hand | 0 | 0 |

Here is the logic that I need to provide in order to dynamically calculate the stack size:

1. if the event is in **('bets', 'calls', 'big blind', 'small blind', 'raises')**, it should subtract the value in **stack_size** from **amount**
2. after step 1 is complete, and if there is event from the same list, it should now subtract the value from **result** at the previous row from the **amount** value at the current row
3. the logic from step 2 should continue until there is event in **('bet_return', 'win')**, and now it should sum value from the **result** at the previous row with the value from the **amount** at the current row
4. these operations should be performed within the `hand` and `player` groups - suppose there are many different players (with different stack sizes) and hands

I have a hard to come up with a proper function (in excel it was easy). Any advice would be highly appreciative.

I defined this function, but it takes only the current row into account and doesn't yield the desired output:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'hand': ['#345', '#345', '#345', '#345', '#345', '#345', '#345'],
        'player': ['paired', 'paired', 'paired', 'paired', 'paired', 'paired', 'paired'],
        'event': ['win', 'bet returned', 'bets', 'bets', 'raises', 'stack', 'starting hand'],
        'amount': [144, 72, 72, 43, 18, 0, 0],
        'stack_size': [552, 552, 552, 552, 552, 552, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def adjust_stack(row):
    if row['event'] in (
        'bets', 'calls', 'big blind',
        'small blind', 'raises'
    ):
        return row['stack_size'] - row['amount']
    elif row['event'] in ('bet_returned', 'win'):
        return row['stack_size'] + row['amount']
    else:
        return row['stack_size']

df.assign(
    result = logs.apply(adjust_stack, axis=1)
).query('hand=="#345" and player=="paired"')
```

| hand | player | event | amount | stack_size | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #345 | paired | win | 144 | 552 | 696 |
| #345 | paired | bet returned | 72 | 552 | 552 |
| #345 | paired | bets | 72 | 552 | 480 |
| #345 | paired | bets | 43 | 552 | 509 |
| #345 | paired | raises | 18 | 552 | 534 |
| #345 | paired | stack | 0 | 552 | 552 |
| #345 | paired | starting hand | 0 | NaN | NaN |

But the output should be like this, given the logic I provided:

| hand | player | event | amount | stack_size | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #345 | paired | win | 144 | 552 | 635 |
| #345 | paired | bet returned | 72 | 552 | 491 |
| #345 | paired | bets | 72 | 552 | 419 |
| #345 | paired | bets | 43 | 552 | 491 |
| #345 | paired | raises | 18 | 552 | 534 |
| #345 | paired | stack | 0 | 552 |  |
| #345 | paired | starting hand | 0 | 0 |  |

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have your dataframe defined as `df`, it should be a straight forward call to `apply` using your `adjust_stack` method.

Example

```py
# Apply the adjust_stack function to each row of the DataFrame
df['calculated_column'] = df.apply(adjust_stack, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Call the column whatever you want. Here `axis=1` tells the method to loop by each row.

Comment: I've provided an example of what my function yields as of now

Comment: I see your requirements are more complex. I assumed your `adjust_stack` was enough. I think you need to revise your logic because it doesn't line up with 1) your code or 2) your "expected" output. In fact your expected output seems to not follow any logic you've listed. Double check.